# Android crash only above oreo , below is the stack trace of the crash . If anybody have the idea then please share

Tags: android, amazon-s3

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory; at
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility.(TransferUtility.java:91)
>   at
>   com.amazons3library.AmazonUtils.getTransferUtility(AmazonUtils.java:28)
>   at com.amazons3library.AmazonS3.uploadImage(AmazonS3.java:60) at
>   com.healthgroup.activity.NewGroupActivity.startUpload(NewGroupActivity.java:1260)
>   at
>   com.healthgroup.activity.NewGroupActivity.onActivityResult(NewGroupActivity.java:1193)
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7462) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4391) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4440)
>   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
>   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.healthgroup-Xo-La3W311JYbhhYhF2oXg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.healthgroup-Xo-La3W311JYbhhYhF2oXg==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/com.healthgroup-Xo-La3W311JYbhhYhF2oXg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64]] at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

Comment: I'm guessing you put a stray annotation or `if` block to check for versions, then forgot about it when you updated the code or added a new library (Speaking from experience)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer of my problem . In case someone face the same issue just add these lines in to the application element in the manifest file

```
<uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false"/>
```